# change activity launch mode to singleInstance makes me lose my custom animation

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I change activity launch mode to `singleInstance` in *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity
     android:name=".Photos"
     android:launchMode="singleInstance"
     android:label="Photos"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

but it makes me lost my cutom animation in styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right </item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left </item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right </item>
</style>
```

which has been working fine before adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` attribute to *AndroidManifest.xml*

any help please ?

Comment: Why do you think you need `singleInstance` launch mode? Please explain.

Comment: any solution to this issue?